# Delete row without missing an iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I'm trying to sort some data that is in a pandas dataframe. I need to sort them by a specific value in column 1. Column 1 has 28 unique values. In the end I want 28 dataframes and for each dataframe the value in column 1 is the same.

I have a working algorithm, the problem is, my dataset has 437000 rows, iterating over these rows 28 times takes forever.

```
for i in range(size_unique):
    for j in range(size_data):
        if unique_values[i] == data_set.iloc[j, 0]:
            dict[unique_values[i]] = pd.concat([dict[unique_values[i]], data_set.iloc[j,:]])
```

My new dataframes are in a dictionary and it works perfectly fine apart from the time issue.

My idea was to delete a row as soon as a match is found. However, that would lower the index of the next row and subsequently the row wouldn't be checked. Is there a way around this? Or please tell me if there is a more elegant solution

Sample data:

| type | uuid | org_name | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| angel | akeb | business1 | 2000 |
| seeed | aezr | business2 | 5000 |
| series_a | yxxc | business3 | 2999 |
| series_a | pepr | business1 | 8989 |
| series_c | aerw | business4 | 12312 |

The unique values I wish to sort by here, are [angel, seed, series_a, series_c], the uuid is a unique value that corresponds to the transaction and nothing else. The whole dataset is information concerning funding rounds for different businesses.

In this reduced case, I want 1 dataframe that lists all transactions of type 'angel', 1 dataframe that lists all transactions of type 'seed', etc.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input data and the expected output?

Comment: `looping` in pandas is an _anti-pattern_ you need to provide a proper example of your dataframe for anyone to provide some proper help. see [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: Added a table with sample data, although I don't know how helpful it is, since the problem really only lies with the size of my dataset..

Comment: why not do the deletion after all rows are processed?

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) will do the operation for you by grouping rows by values in the "type" column. `groupby` will iterate pairs of `value:grouped_dataframe` values that you can turn into the dictionary you want. Or, depending on what you want to do next, you can just use the returned `DataFrameGroupBy` object instead.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""type,uuid,org_name,amount
angel,akeb,business1,2000
seeed,aezr,business2,5000
series_a,yxxc,business3,2999
series_a,pepr,business1,8989
series_c,aerw,business4,12312"""))

# optionally categorize data for performance
df = df.astype({"type":"category", "org_name":"category"})

mapping = dict(iter(df.groupby("type")))
for name, df2 in mapping.items():
    print("--->", name)
    print(df2.head())
```